# How to install an AIR android app without deleting the data generated by the previous version

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an android app developed using adobe AIR SDK 16 and Flash CS6. Every time i publish/debug the app directly in the connected device. But every time i publish the app the data(image, text files) saved in the application storage directory including the sqlite file is removed. Hence i have to recreate all the data again to test. Is there a way to install/public an apk without losing the data created by the installed app? I tried with changing the version number. But it did not work. Please help me

thanks

Comment: This is normal and you are the one responsible for this. If you want something to be delete each time you install your app then you put that in the application directory as you do, if you don't want that then you need to put that in another folder like the storage directory.

Comment: can i put the sqlite file in the storage directory? and for ios app i cannot access the storage directory. So how do i do it here?

Comment: the applicationStorageDirectory is accessible on android and Ios and not overwritten when installing new versions.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the replay, I found a way (from adobe forum). When we update an app from google play, the data will not be deleted. In my case the data is deleted because flash will first uninstall the app(this will clear the data) then install the new app again. To solve this, one way is instead of publishing directly use flash to publish the app and copy the apk into the android device and use any file explorer software to install it manually. This will not delete the data